# switch and if in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Why does the following work (compile):

```
public void SaveCurrentTab(string currentTabIndex)
        {
            if (currentTabIndex == MainInfoPnl.ClientID)
                PartialSave1();
            else if (currentTabIndex == ContactInfoPnl.ClientID)
                PartialSave2();
            else if (currentTabIndex == BankInfoPnl.ClientID)
                PartialSave3();
            else if (currentTabIndex == ServicesPnl.ClientID)
                PartialSave4();
            else if (currentTabIndex == AttachmentsPnl.ClientID)
                PartialSave5();

        }
```

But, the following does not?

```
public void SaveCurrentTab(string currentTabIndex)
        {
            switch (currentTabIndex)
            {
                case MainInfoPnl.ClientID:
                    PartialSave1();
                    break;
                case ContactInfoPnl.ClientID:
                    PartialSave2();
                    break;
                case BankInfoPnl.ClientID:
                    PartialSave3();
                    break;
                case ServicesPnl.ClientID:
                    PartialSave4();
                    break;
                case AttachmentsPnl.ClientID:
                    PartialSave5();
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: It's a language restriction. C# limits the switch expressions to integral types (more strictly, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0t5wee3(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: "does not work" is a horrible problem description.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably because `MainInfoPnl.ClientID` isn't a compile-time constant. It may be `public static readonly` for example, which isn't the same as [`const`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx). If that doesn't help, show us more about the code and the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

The case statements must be constant strings for a `switch` - an `if` condition has no such restriction.

Answer (score 2):

A switch in C# only works with constant values. For values determined at runtime, use a if-else construction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void SaveCurrentTab(string currentTabIndex)
        {
            switch (Convert.ToInt32(currentTabIndex))
            {
                case (int)MainInfoPnl.ClientID:
                    PartialSave1();
                    break;
                case (int)ContactInfoPnl.ClientID:
                    PartialSave2();
                    break;
                case (int)BankInfoPnl.ClientID:
                    PartialSave3();
                    break;
                case (int)ServicesPnl.ClientID:
                    PartialSave4();
                    break;
                case (int)AttachmentsPnl.ClientID:
                    PartialSave5();
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: It's not a typing issue, it is compile time constant vs. runtime values.

Comment: Assuming that those fields aren't readonly compile-time consts yes. For values created at runtime, switch won't work. As simple if-else should be used in those situations.